# what is the best study guide for the LPIC2 exam

Tags: linux

Can anyone recommend a good study guide/book for the LPIC2 exam besides the Sybex/Roderick Smith book?

Answer (score 3):

Online, I prefer [IBM DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/). But for LPIC2 isn't totally covered.

Adicionally, I will add non-english books. Feel free to ignore. For someone else could be interesting.

- [CERTIFICAÇÃO LPI-2](http://www.altabooks.com.br/certificacao-lpi-2-201-202.html)
- [Guia FOCA](http://www.guiafoca.org/?page_id=51)