# Common problems and scenarios for Linux certification study

Tags: linux

I'm trying to learn Linux online to get a LPIC-1 certificate. But trying to identify and combine the right tools in the right place is very hard.
So I was wondering if a list of scenarios that users or admins have to face (preferably sorted based on difficulty and again preferably with answers) is available.

For example the course teacher mentioned that they had to extend the space available on some path because their logs were growing big. Or he said that we could create triggers for hardware events so when a special drive is connected, some special command (e.g. for backup) would run.

I have tried to search online with many keywords but I haven't been able to find a good resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking of my experience, I have *LPIC1* since 2012 and so far haven't found that dream scenario either.

Although the books I read have code examples for every command. Not to mention you can find snippets and usage in all over internet.

In my opinion, unfortunately the certification has tricky question and it basically forces you to memorize the less used options, flags and weird combination of commands. Speaking of scenarios, I remember the exams had many unrealistic scenarios.

So, I suggest you to study every command required and make a use of as many flags and options as you can. For professional experience think of a scenario is very helpful, but not for the exams.

PS: an almost unrelated, but still helpful answer is this [what-is-the-best-study-guide-for-the-lpic2-exam](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153800/what-is-the-best-study-guide-for-the-lpic2-exam).